# Cannot type object where each key maps to a generic value

Tags: typescript

I am having some issues typing an object where *each* key maps to a generic value.

I have simplified my code down to this minimum reproducible example:

```
export type Action<T extends string, P> = {
    type: T;
    error: false;
    payload: P;
};

type Event = { action: string; [trait: string]: string; };

type Handlers = {
    [key: string]: <T extends string, P>(action: Action<T, P>) => Event;
};

export type ActionAType = Action<
    "ACTION_A",
    { id: number; a: string; }
>;


export type ActionBType = Action<
    "ACTION_B",
    { id: number; b: string }
>;

const HANDLERS: Handlers = {
    "QUERY_GROUP_START": (action: ActionAType) => {
        return { action: "START", a: action.payload.a };
    },

    "QUERY_GROUP_CONTINUE": (action: ActionBType) => {
        return { action: "CONTINUE", id: action.payload.id };
    }
};
```

I have an `Action` generic type and some instances of that generic type (`ActionA`, `ActionB`) and I want my `Handlers` type to correspond to an object where each element is a generic key-value pair.

The error I get is:

```
Type '(action: ActionAType) => { action: string; a: string; }' is not assignable to type '<T extends string, P>(action: Action<T, P>) => Event'.
  Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
    Type 'Action<T, P>' is not assignable to type 'ActionAType'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type '"ACTION_A"'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"ACTION_A"'.(2322)
```

The reason that I need this pattern is because I have an array of action handlers in a Redux middleware.

The `middleware` function works this way:

1. It receives an action (type is `Action`)
2. Calls the handler for that action

This middleware is in a library so it doesn't have the list of handlers. Instead, the client of the library passes in a list of handlers when the middleware is configured.

```
export const coreAnalytics = (
    customHandlers: Handlers
) => () => (next: (action: Action) => void) => (action: Action) => {
    const customHandler: (action: Action) => Event =
        customHandlers[action.type];

    if (customHandler) {
        const analyticsEvent: Event = customHandler(action);

        ...
    }

    ...
};
```

Notice that there is no union type for `Action` here. If we had that, this would be pretty simple to rewrite as a function that switches on the action type and handles each action.

I have a playground link here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBjGBLCA7AHgBU5QZg8ATAZzmpimzwHMAaOABQD44BeOAN4BYAFBxxCZMABccIgG5RE0lCjRZAMwCGAG2rBFYiWC2IdELZVkdDAX0OikKOAAktVHcCi1+wo+IBtAGtgRFl6RhYAXVliUhByKloIpjZOLgAKLSxcPFlMHHxidm4ASj4eACMICE93OwcRUEhYSWcC3LQiKT50HKKlCQAiNABhIgBJAHkAOQB9NCHWQfEBOGwrODwAVwBbSq95OC1whlSj21EuRtFm6HgnVA78ACFu535nwhW4EfHp+YvJY-NYbWQ7faHOCVU6RZhwS4ia6iUQYfD0VxoGYAEQAMgBRABKAGVZG4PF4fIIfkMAIoAVSJAE05gBxQlTekcObEohoQlEIayLL9PJ9Qp4LpScq8Hh+ZTKKDAGDbKB4BBQbYGH62ZYiGkM5lsjlcuajWaTGaMoVwEUS-Kit7SirU-wKpUqtVwbR6bVuxH2IA

Comment: Why do you need `Handlers` as a type here? What would be its use? Why can't it be `type Handlers = typeof HANDLERS`?

Comment: @Federkun great question, I've updated the question to explain that as best as I could.

Comment: The Redux committee is generally moving away from typing actions as a union type.  Redux maintainer @phry has an article about this: https://phryneas.de/redux-typescript-no-discriminating-union I’ll take a more detailed look at your question later, but there are definitely ways to set this up that avoid the TS issue rather than addressing it directly.

Comment: This is due to the concept of [variance](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: Have you tried to use interface instead of type it makes things much more easier if your Action is an interface of 
```
export interface Action {
    type: string;
    error: boolean;
    payload: any;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: in an object of type `Handlers`, the only guarantee when a one of the function properties is called is that its `action` argument will be an `Action<T, P>`. The `T` could be any `string` and the `P` could be anything at all. That makes it an error to ask for any more specific guarantee when assigning a property to a `Handlers` object. In your two cases, you ask for `action` to be specifically `ActionAType` and `ActionBType`, meaning that you ask for `T` to be specifically `'ACTION_A'` and `'ACTION_B'` and for `P` to be specifically `{ id: number; a: string; }` and `{ id: number; b: string }`. That's too specific for how `Handlers` is typed.

I agree with Federkun that the best approach is not to explicitly type `HANDLERS`. (In fact, you might not need `Handlers` at all, not even as an alias.) Without an explicit type, each property on the object has its own narrower type with the relevant guarantees about `T` and `P`.

If your full code has some reason to need explicit typing on `HANDLERS`, then you might need to update/expand your example to reflect that.

Comment: this is very insightful and you're right that it needs more context so I've edited my question to have some more context explaining why I need this.

Answer (score 0):

`const HANDLERS: Handlers` looses type information of the assigned value, so
it seems to me that you could just type a single handler as: `(action: Action<any, any>) => boolean;`.

If you would like to keep your type information available and make sure handlers are still of appropriate shape you could use constrained identity function like that:

```
const asHandlers = <HS extends Handlers>(hs: HS) => hs

const HANDLERS_TYPED = asHandlers({
    "QUERY_GROUP_START": (action: ActionAType) => {
        return true;
    },

    "QUERY_GROUP_CONTINUE": (action: ActionBType) => {
        return false;
    }
})
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=44&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBjGBLCA7AHgBU5QZg8ATAZzmpimzwHMAaOABQD44BeOAN4BYAFBxxCZMABccIgG5RE0lCjRZAMwCGAG2rBFYiWC2IdELZVkdDAX0OikKOAAktVHcCi1+wo+IBtAGtgRFl6RhYAXVkACi0sXDxZTBx8AndEdkyuAEo+HgAjCAhPdzsHEVBIWElnVKS0Iik+dET0pQkAIjQAYSIASQB5ADkAfTQu1k7xAThsKzg8AFcAW0KveTgtcIYmZi3bUS5K0WroeCdUBvwAIWbnfhvCGbge-uHx26nXuYXZFbrTZwQq7SLMOBHEQnUSiDD4eiuNAjAAiABkAKIAJQAyrI3B4vD5BK8ugBFACq2IAmmMAOJYoYUjhjHFENBYohdOIJNLJNp8ppSfK8Hh+ZTKKDAGDLKB4BBQZYGV62aYiUmUmn0xnMsa9UaDEZU7lweLtfnPe7Cgok-wSqUyuVwbR6ZV2qH2WHqkTwvCIrTUAmUTzeVoEFw40ggchUWhBkPULixAAW1HxOJFPFTXt9iJcyPR2JxYyI1I4GJRrQD8aJsXF3U1WNpDKZLLZHK5PPNKXNQpQmdtEokDtl8oYSsMylVXuU5KpTe1rb1BoGRoxJrNfJ7fKt-Zt9aHI6dLv0k4kHtyoiAA)

[image]